# Kusto, Can't User gettype() function?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

in kusto (KQL) I'm trying to print type of column in my table so I did:

```
SamplePowerRequirementHistorizedData
| print gettype(my_column_name)
```

which failed, so I replaced `my_column_name` with `5` and it failed too. How may I fix this?

The error message says:

```
The operator must be the first operator in the query.(KS175)
```

Which doesn't make sense as I need the table name to be first... (to access its columns)

Answer (score 0):

1. i believe you intended to use the `project` operator and not the `print` operator
2. given that the type is the same for the entire column, and you don't need to get it per record, you can use the `getschema` operator instead:

```
TableName
| getschema
| where ColumnName == "MyColumn"
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain why project works while print doesn't? what's the difference?

Comment: the `project` operator allows selecting the columns to include, rename, or insert as new computed columns, whereas the `print` operator only takes one or more scalar expressions as its input (it can't take a tabular input (e.g. `T | `), and outputs a table with a single-row with those scalar expressions as columns.